# Are there nonlinear operators that have the group property?

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, lie-groups

To be clear: What I am actually talking about is a nonlinear operator on a *finitely generated vector space* V  with dimension $d(V)\;\in \mathbb{N}>1$. I can think of several nonlinear operators on such a vector space but none of them have the requisite properties of a group. In particular, but not exclusively, are there any such nonlinear operator groups that meet the definition of a Lie Group.

Comment: Are you asking "*are there any non-linear operators from $V$ to $V$ that are group homomorphisms?*" or are you asking "*are there any collections of non-linear operators from $V$ to $V$ that form a group?*" ?

Comment: I'm asking if there are any collections of nonlinear operators from V to V that form a group.

Comment: Does "nonlinear operator" have any particular meaning here I'm not aware of, or is it just an arbitrary map (of sets)? Pick your favourite three points in V, say a, b and c, and permute them around. (This is just a non-linear action of $S_3$ on V - you can do this with any group you like on any V that has enough points.)

Comment: Yes it does, billy. If V is our n-dimensional vector space,f is a mapping from V to V, and A & B are any 2 vectors in V,then f is *linear* iff f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B) which is called the superposition principle. A nonlinear map f from V to V is one where f(A+B)!=f(A)+f(B).

Comment: **[Now posted on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132692/nonlinear-operatorswith-the-group-property)**.

Answer (score 3):

As some guy once said, dividing operators into linear and nonlinear is like dividing the world into bananas and nonbananas. If you're ignoring the vector space structure on $V$ then it's just a set, and you're just asking for a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). It is easy to write down group actions, even Lie group actions (see [homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space)), on a vector space that just don't happen to be linear. Probably the simplest example is $\mathbb{R}$ acting on itself by translation.

Comment: Based on Mr X's clarification in the comments, the $\mathbb{R}$ action on itself by left translation is "linear".  (Mr X, perhaps nonstandardly, doesn't mention scalar multiplication!).  That said, examples still abound.  Pick your favorite nonlinear automorphism $f$ (in whatever category you wish, so long as the category contains the linear maps).  Then conjugating $Gl(V)$ by $f$ will givea group of nonlinear things.

Comment: Er... no it's not?

Comment: Wow - I really shouldn't be doing math after midnight I apologize!  I can delete my whole rant if you'd prefer.  (And that would be my preference, but whatever.)

Comment: Thanks, Jason DeVito! And Quiaochu Yuan, I was asking for examples of nonlinear transformations on a vector space $V^{n}\;$ where n > 1. I'm aware that a nonlinear maps of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^{1} \to \mathbb{R}^{1} \;$ form a translation group.

Comment: Examples are just as easy to write down in the higher-dimensional case. Jason DeVito's comment works in all dimensions.

Comment: That's true Mr Yuan. As DeVito pointed you, you can conjugate a nonlinear transformation with a linear transformation from GL(V,n) and that forms a group. But I'll keep on lookin for one that has the group property by itself under some binary operation besides addition & multiplication. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Oh I've got one....

Let A by a non-singular, invertible square matrix whose elements are components of vectors in $V^{n}$. Now consider the operator $T(\hat{v}) = e^{A\hat{v}}, \; \;\forall \hat{v} \in V^{n}$. So if $\alpha,\beta$ are any such operators with corresponding  invertible non-singular matrices (A,B) respectively, than the binary group operation is $\phi(\alpha,\beta) = e^{AB\hat{v}} = (e^{A\hat{v}})^{B}$ where AB is the product matrix A*B. The inverse operator is $T^{-1}(\hat{v}) = A^{-1} ln(\hat{v})$.The identity mapping is $\hat{I}(\hat{v})= e^{ln(\hat{v})}=\hat{v}$.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following construction. Let $M \in R_{d}(G)$ be a $d$ dimensional representation of some Lie group (e.g. $SL(2,R)$ and $V$ is some $d$ dimensional vector space. Now define:
$$
f(x,M,\epsilon)= \frac{M x}{(1+\epsilon w.x)}
$$
where the vector $w$ is chosen so that $w.M= w$ for all $M\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Such vectors exist, for instance, if $d=4$ and $R_4(G)=R_2(G) \otimes R_2(G)$ then $w=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ is one such vector. It is now not too difficult to convince oneself that:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
f(x,I,0) = x \\
f(f(x,M_1,\epsilon_1),M_2,\epsilon_2) = f(x,M_1 M_2,\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)
\end{eqnarray}$$
so that the mapping $f$ is nonlinear and satisfies the group property.